Correct A4950 usage
I want to control a DC motor (24 V) with an ESP32.
Instead of creating my own H-Bridge I decided to use an A4950:

[...] A4950 is capable of peak output currents to ±3.5 A
and operating voltages to 40 V.[...]
controlling the speed and direction [... with] PWM [...]
Internal circuit protection includes overcurrent protection,
motor lead short to ground or supply, thermal shutdown with
hysteresis, undervoltage monitoring of VBB, and crossover-
current protection.


Here is how I integrated the A4950 in my circuit:

The h-bridge-1 and h-bridge-2 go directly to the ESP32.  The H-Bridge-Out1 and H-Bridge-Out2 directly to the DC motor.
I have tested the motor with a power supply and never run into an over current situation when limiting the power supply to 2.5 A (at 24 V).
However, when using my circuit (and a “normal” 24 V power supply without limiting features) driving the motor in one direction for 2.5s followed by a pause of 10 s, and then trying to run the motor in the reverse direction for 2.5 s, the chip started to burn (looks really nice, but the smell...).
  A4950-1.set 0
  A4950-2.set 0
  
  A4950-1.set 1
  sleep --ms=2500

  A4950-1.set 0
  sleep --ms=15000

  A4950-2.set 1
  sleep --ms=2500

  A4950-2.set 0


I bought the chips on Aliexpress.
Did I do something wrong?  Shouldn't the protections of the A4950 prevent this?
I am kind of hoping that my chips are fake (and I am currently ordering from digikey).
What is your opinion?


[edit]
Thanks to a comment from Jens I've realized, that the power rating for R9 is too low.  R9 did not survive the failure and was only rated for 250mW.
At 2.5 A it needed to dissipate 625mW.
IMO this still doesn't explain why the protections of the A4950 didn't kick in.
The motor is a reduction motor with the following specifications:
No-load current: < 200 mA
Rated current: < 1 A
Stall current: 2.8 A
It's the yellow column in the 24V table.
The motor is still working.
(I am pushing ~2 A through the motor even though it is only rated for less than 1 A.)


What is the rated power for R9? Did it survive the failure?

Is the PWR_FLAG node connected to anything else other than R9 and the LSS pin of the A4950?

Please explain the close vote. [Close votes without explanation are allowed by the system. And/But: Closed questions without reasons explained MAY be reopened without reasons explained. ]

@RussellMcMahon the op is asking for opinions both implicitly and explicitly. The motor loading is also not specified hence, more information is required. It would be better if he'd waited until digi-key chips arrived so that anyone answering can rule out the whole fake-chip debate (unresolvable at this level).

The PWR_FLAG node is connected to a pin GPIO33 on the ESP32.  I wanted to measure the current using the ADC functionality of the ESP32 but haven't implemented it yet.

Did R9 fail open-circuit or short-circuit? Since the voltage drop across R9 is used as the current sense, if failed short-circuit possibly could have circumvented the over-current protection in the A4950 leading to destruction of the A4950.
